# HAProxy rewrite sticky session cookie on backend failure

Tags: haproxy

I have HAProy load balancing two Tomcats and using sticky sessions. When server A goes down subsequent requests from the same session are served by B. But, if server A comes up again, additional requests from the same session are routed to A. What I want to do is rewrite the cookie so that after A goes down all requests from the same session are routed to B, even if A comes up again.

httpd with mod_jk has this functionality using `JvmRouteBinderValve`. Is something similar available for HAProxy?

Comment: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: That's a general explanation of session stickiness but as far as I can tell it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: is not only general explanation, when ask for help show your config not only description of the issue, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation looks like changing configuration from `cookie JSESSIONID prefix` to `cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache` does the trick.

Comment: I am happy that doc help you :)